# how to use custom_data field of azurerm_virtual_machine resource in terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use custom_data field of resource azurerm_virtual_machine, but getting caught up into this error. Any idea what I am missing or is that a wrong usage?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "csrVM" {
  name                  = "csr-terraform-poc"
  location              = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraformRG.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.terraformNic1.id}",
                           "${azurerm_network_interface.terraformNic2.id}"]
  primary_network_interface_id = "${azurerm_network_interface.terraformNic1.id}"
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  custom_data = "${file("customdata.txt")}"
  #custom_data = <<CUSTOMDATA
  #username testuser privilege 15 password testpass
  #enable password testpass
#CUSTOMDATA
```

~>terraform apply -var-file=azure.tfvars

**Error: azurerm_virtual_machine.csrVM: : invalid or unknown key: custom_data**

~>terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.3
+ provider.azurerm v1.1.1

Comment: I'm unable to find any links on how to pass scripts to this custom_data field. Can you send me any reference links.??

Comment: as mentioned in answer. it is os_profile node. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#custom_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used terraform, but looking at the [resource definition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html) you need to create a os_profile node and place custom_data there.

os_profile supports the following:

```
computer_name - (Required) Specifies the name of the virtual machine.  
admin_username - (Required) Specifies the name of the administrator account.  
admin_password - (Required for Windows, Optional for Linux) Specifies the password of the administrator account.  
custom_data - (Optional) Specifies custom data to supply to the machine. On linux-based systems, this can be used as a cloud-init script. On other systems, this will be copied as a file on disk. Internally, Terraform will base64 encode this value before sending it to the API. The maximum length of the binary array is 65535 bytes.
```

Comment: I missed the line "os profile supports the following" while referencing terraform documentation. Thanks for catching it up :)

Comment: check this article https://sbulav.github.io/terraform/terraform-azurerm-compute-custom-data/